# How to test Lambda publishing a message via AWS cloud console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a problem with testing the Lambda destination - SNS.

Message is not published after Lambda has successfully run. I invoked the lambda in AWS cloud console using a test event.

Destination and topics are properly configured.

[image]

[image]

Side note, I can programmatically publish a message via `sns.publish()`.

**Question:**
Is there a way to publish a message automatically to SNS once Lambda has successfully run via **AWS console** (using a test event)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The console ["synchronously invokes your function with the test event"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/testing-functions.html?icmpid=docs_lambda_help#invoke-with-event).  It must be invoked [asynchronously](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-async-destinations) to use the destinations.

Call the [lambda invoke](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html) API with `--invocation-type Event` for asynchronous invocation.